# Spring Boot with Kafka Streams throws ClassCastException only when set configuration in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a problem with Spring boot with Kafka Streams.

There are two ways to set configuration Kafka Streams.

First way is set configuration with @Bean like this.

```
@Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
KafkaStreamsConfiguration kStreamsConfig() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-streams");
    props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
}
```

When I using this way and deploy application on k8s, it works well and doesn't throw any Exception.

But, In second way using application.properties like this

```
// application.properties

spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.streams.application-id=kafka-streams
```

When I deploy application with this way on k8s, the application works well too but throw ClassCastException!!

```
20220728 18:08:17 [XTRA-KAFKA-PRPDUCER11 main] class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
java.lang.ClassCastException
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:666)
    org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.DefaultKafkaClientSupplier.getRestoreConsumer(DefaultKafkaClientSupplier.java:49)
    org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.create(StreamThread.java:343)
    org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.createAndAddStreamThread(KafkaStreams.java:956)
    org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:948)
    org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:845)
    org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:751)
    org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:349)
    org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    com.example.springkafka.SpringKafkaApplication.main(SpringKafkaApplication.java:10)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

(That bootstrap-servers is an example. In my application, it isn't localhost:9092)

Additionally, In local environment using IntelliJ, there's no Exception in both ways.

I wonder why this problem is caused. and how to solve this problem..

Comment: "In my application, it isn't localhost:9092" ... Well, is it an **array**? Because the error says it needs to be a string.

Comment: umm... not array. it is just a String like `spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`. But as I know, in application.properties, using like `spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094` when value is array. I think that it is not cause... I tried not only using application.properties but also using application.yaml like `spring:kafka:streams:bootstrap-servers: ["localhost:9092"]`.

Comment: `localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094` is a string. `spring:kafka:streams:bootstrap-servers` is not a valid `.properties` entry, but `["localhost:9092"]` is a list. And when `props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, value);` gets auto-configured by Spring Boot, it wants a String, not a list. My question was more related to what are you actually using rather than `localhost:9092`?

Comment: I used `spring:kafka:streams:bootstrap-servers` in application.yaml. Now, I'm using only one bootstrap-servers like `spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`.

Comment: Bootstrap servers aren't just a Streams property. [You should just set `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`, or in yaml/json, the object format would be `{spring: {kafka: {bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092}}`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka). Then this gets used over all clients.

Comment: Oh , I will try it tomorrow and comment result. thank you.

Comment: Did you try comma-separated list for YAML config as well? Kinda: `spring:kafka:streams:bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094`. Or `-` list item: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.yaml.mapping-to-properties

Comment: No. I tried comma-separated list on properties file. and I'm using just one host.

Comment: it doesn't works.. Still throw exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to ignore this Exception.

Because, When the exception thrown, application does not shut down or it works well.

Furthermore, In local environment, exception does not be thrown.

I think there's some problem in my k8s.

Thanks for all comments.